# How can I create a column with counts between a column and a list in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a column `df['score']` that returns the count of values in common between a cell and a list.

Input:

```
correct_list = ['cats','dogs']
  answer       
0 cats, dogs, pigs
1 cats, dogs        
2 dogs, pigs        
3 cats              
4 pigs     

def animal_count(dataframe):
    count = 0
    for term in df['answer']:
        if term in symptom_list:
            df['score'] = count + 1

animal_count(df)
```

Intended Output:

```
correct_list = ['cats','dogs']

  answer            score
0 cats, dogs, pigs  2
1 cats, dogs        2
2 dogs, pigs        1
3 cats              1
4 pigs              0
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution using [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['score'] = df['answer'].str.count('|'.join(correct_list))
```

[out]

```
             answer  score
0  cats, dogs, pigs      2
1        cats, dogs      2
2        dogs, pigs      1
3              cats      1
4              pigs      0
```

---

#### Update

As pointed out by @PrinceFrancis, if `catsdogs` shouldn't be counted as `2`, then you can change your regex pattern to suit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'answer': ['cats, dogs, pigs', 'cats, dogs', 'dogs, pigs', 'cats', 'pigs', 'catsdogs']})

pat = '|'.join([fr'\b{x}\b' for x in correct_list])
df['score'] = df['answer'].str.count(pat)
```

[out]

```
             answer  score
0  cats, dogs, pigs      2
1        cats, dogs      2
2        dogs, pigs      1
3              cats      1
4              pigs      0
5          catsdogs      0
```

Comment: this is the correct way to go about this prob I feel

Comment: But it will return 2 for the string `catsdogs`. If `,` matters, then it output is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

We can also use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
df['score']=df['answer'].str.split(', ').explode().isin(correct_list).groupby(level=0).sum()
print(df)
             answer  score
0  cats, dogs, pigs    2.0
1        cats, dogs    2.0
2        dogs, pigs    1.0
3              cats    1.0
4              pigs    0.0
```

Comment: Vectorized answers are great, but at this point I'm genuinely curious when or if a simple `apply` function might outperform several linked operations, and at what data size do we start seeing the difference.  Please don't mind my curiosity if it appears to be unenlightened.

Answer (score 4):

You could do as follows

```py
correct_list = ['cats','dogs']
df['score'] = df['answer'].str.split(', ')
df['score'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x: sum(el in x for el in correct_list))
df
```

It will give you the following result

```
    answer  score
0   cats,dogs,pigs  2
1   cats,dogs   2
2   dogs,pigs   1
3   cats    1
4   pigs    0
```

Comment: Likely want to `str.split(', ')` to match OP's dataframe (i.e. with an extra whitespace at the end) ;} - may also be nice to test whether or not a list comprehension would have better performance instead of `apply` (I'd guess it would)

Comment: @rafaelc, I update my answer. Thanks for noticing it. Not sure about the performance of my answer, still learning python. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You can measure the intersecting `set` between the two `list`s:

```
>>> df['score'] = df['answer'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & set(correct_list)))
>>> df
             answer  score
0  cats, dogs, pigs      2
1        cats, dogs      2
2        dogs, pigs      1
3              cats      1
4              pigs      0
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
correct_list = ['cats','dogs']
df = pd.DataFrame(['cats, dogs, pigs', 'cats, dogs', 'dogs, pigs', 'cats', 'pigs'], columns=['answer'])

df['score'] = df.answer.str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: sum([1 for a in x if a in correct_list]))
```

Result:

```
             answer  score
0  cats, dogs, pigs      2
1        cats, dogs      2
2        dogs, pigs      1
3              cats      1
4              pigs      0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_func(x):
    return sum([1 for y in x.split(',') if y.strip() in correct_list])

df['score'] = df['answer'].apply(my_func)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
correct_list = ['cats', 'dogs']
answer = ['cats,dogs,pigs','cats,dogs','dogs,pigs','cats','pigs']
answer = [ans.split(',') for ans in answer]
score = [0] * len(answer)
df = pd.DataFrame({'answer':answer,'score':score})
print(df,'\n')
df.score = df.answer.apply(lambda cell: len(set(cell) & set(correct_list)))
print(df)

"""
               answer  score
0  [cats, dogs, pigs]      0
1        [cats, dogs]      0
2        [dogs, pigs]      0
3              [cats]      0
4              [pigs]      0 

               answer  score
0  [cats, dogs, pigs]      2
1        [cats, dogs]      2
2        [dogs, pigs]      1
3              [cats]      1
4              [pigs]      0
"""
```